# ArgumentException when converting byte[] to Bitmap c#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, web-services

I'm trying to convert a byte array to a bitmap but it always shows me:

> System.ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid.

My code is as follows:

I'm passing the bytes through a webservice with:

```
 string DecodedString = string.Empty;
 DecodedString = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1251).GetString(bytes);
 sResult = sResult + "<Photo>" +XmlConvert.EncodeName(DecodedString) + "</Photo>";
```

and in my webPage:

```
byte[] bytes = (Byte[])System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1251).GetBytes(XmlConvert.DecodeName(xDocument.SelectSingleNode("Response/Images/Photo").InnerText));
    System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(bytes);

    System.Drawing.Bitmap b = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(ms);//(System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms));
```

Answer (score 2):

Try passing the string as a Base64:

```
string DecodedString = string.Empty;
DecodedString = System.Convert.ToBase64String(bytes)
sResult = sResult + "<Photo>" +XmlConvert.EncodeName(DecodedString) + "</Photo>";
```

...

```
byte[] bytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(xDocument.SelectSingleNode("Response/Images/Photo").InnerText);
System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(bytes);
System.Drawing.Bitmap b = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);
```

You also won't need to use XmlConvert to encode/decode the string.

Comment: But if I dont use the enconde/decode the xml cannot be read it throws an invalid xml exception..

Comment: *Don't* put a using statement round the stream in this case. When you've called Image.FromStream, you *mustn't* close the stream, or the image will be broken. When you dispose the image, *that* will close the stream.

Comment: D'oh. I was in a hurry when I wrote the answer and didn't actually read the entire code :/

Answer (score 2):

I did it, with the help of all of you, here is my page code

```
 byte[] bytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(xDocument.SelectSingleNode("Response/Images/Photo").InnerText);


   System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(bytes);

   System.Drawing.Bitmap b = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(ms); //(Bitmap)System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);

   System.Drawing.Imaging.FrameDimension frameDim;
   frameDim = new System.Drawing.Imaging.FrameDimension(b.FrameDimensionsList[0]);


   int NumberOfFrames = b.GetFrameCount(frameDim);
   string[] paths = new string[NumberOfFrames];

   for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfFrames; i++)
   {
     b.SelectActiveFrame(frameDim, i);

     System.Drawing.Bitmap bmp = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(b);
     paths[i] = imagePathfile.Remove(imagePathfile.Length - 4, 4) + i.ToString() + ".gif";

     bmp.Save(paths[i], System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
     //bmp.Save(Response.OutputStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
     bmp.Dispose();
   }

    Image1.Src = paths[0];
    //Check if there's more than 1 image cause its a TIFF
    if (paths.Length>1)
    {
      Image2.Src = paths[1];  
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem recently, but using Silverlight.  I ended up needing to create a Custom HTTP Handler in order to pass the byte[] that defined the image back as a stream.

See http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=220

Edit:  This allows you to avoid worrying about XML encoding, and passes the image back in Binary form...  YMMV

Comment: Where are you getting the byte[]?  Are you sure the data within the array is correct?

Comment: the byte is coming from:

  System.IO.FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream(sPath, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read);
      int streamLength = Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length);
      bytes = new byte[streamLength];
      fs.Read(bytes, 0, streamLength);

in the web Service.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
byte[] bytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(xDocument.SelectSingleNode("Response/Images/Photo").InnerText);
System.Drawing.ImageConverter imageConverter = new System.Drawing.ImageConverter();
Image image = imageConverter.ConvertFrom(bytes) as Image;
System.Drawing.Bitmap b = new System.Drawing.BitMap(image);
```

**EDIT**

Take a look at this:

[Transfer any files on Web services by c#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webservices/Transfer_any_files_on_Web.aspx)

Comment: Now the error is in this line and its the same **Parameter is Not Valid Error**

System.Drawing.Image image = imageConverter.ConvertFrom(bytes) as System.Drawing.Image;

Comment: Check bytes.Length, make sure that you actually have bytes in the byte array.

Comment: checked,still the same issue.
the byte is coming from: System.IO.FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream(sPath, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read); int streamLength = Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length); bytes = new byte[streamLength]; fs.Read(bytes, 0, streamLength); in the web Service

Comment: Something is wrong with your byte array, I don't thing it's a valid image.

Answer (score 0):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/93z9ee4x.aspx):

> ArgumentException - The stream does not have a valid image format

I believe your problem is in the original `byte[]` array you are passing to the web service.
According to one of your comments, you did:

```
System.IO.FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream(sPath, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read);
int streamLength = Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length);
bytes = new byte[streamLength];
fs.Read(bytes, 0, streamLength);
```

[`fs.Read`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.read.aspx) returns the number of bytes that have been read into the byte array; it doesn't always read the entire file!
Try using the `StreamFile` method from http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/4515-convert-file-into-byte-array.aspx.  (First result of [Google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=file+byte+array+c%23))

Comment: Ok, i'll try this and see if works, but when i dont use a web service the code wirks and the image shows.

Answer (score 0):

actually i had been meet this problem, In my case, when i use IE browser, it is ok but when use another browser it always have the same error.

"Parameter is not valid exception is always happening in the same line of code:
System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms));"

So i think it seems this issue depend on browser and type of image (JPEG,JPEG2000).

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code I used converting bytes to an image for a unit test:

```
    protected override Image LoadImage()
    {
        //get a temp image from bytes, instead of loading from disk
        //data:image/gif;base64,
        byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String("R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==");

        Image image;
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
        {
            image = Image.FromStream(ms);
        }

        return image;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

To my understanding, the image can not be shown because the format of the image's bytes is not correct. Every image format has its own head or something.